# What's wrong with this simple CREATE TABLE?

Tags: mysql

What's wrong with this query ? MySQL doesn't like longblob anymore ??

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE WGS(1 longblob);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 longblob)' at line 1
```

Edit: I changed the column for a Letter it doesn't work as well. Mysql seems to allow only at least 3 characters for column's name..

Comment: Look up the rules for naming columns!

Comment: mssql ? what's the difference ? so far as I know we use mysql :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`WGS` (
`1` LONGBLOB NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

this is correct syntax.

Answer (score 4):

-- EDIT from my original answer, it was completely wrong, sorry about that --

`MySQL` requires you to quote your table column if it's solely digits:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits

I'd suggest changing the naming though, it's quite irritating having to quote your identifier everytime

```
`1` longblob
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it should work:

```
 CREATE TABLE WGS(`1` LONGBLOB);
```

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE TABLE "table_name"
("column_name" "data_type_for_column_name")` and instead you have `1` for column_name. It must be alphanumeric with a letter as a first symbol.